# Exponential Tilting

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, self-learning

Consider a random variable $Y$ with density function $f_Y(y)$ and moment generating function $m_Y(t)$ and cumulant generating function $\kappa_Y(t)$. Then a random variable $X$ derived from $Y$ by the so-called "exponential tilting" has the following density. For some nonzero $\lambda$,

$$
f_X(x; \lambda) := \frac{e^{\lambda x}f_Y(x)}{m_Y(\lambda)} = e^{\lambda x - \kappa_Y(\lambda)}f_Y(x).
$$

> Then the question is to verify that the density function for $S_{n,X}:=X_1 +\cdots+X_n$ is 
>   $$
> f_{S_{n,X}}(s; \lambda) = e^{\lambda s - n\kappa_Y(\lambda)}f_{S_{n,Y}}(s),
> $$
>   where $f_{S_{n,Y}}(s)$ means the density function for $S_{n,Y}:=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$.

This result is only listed in my reading since the authors think it is obvious. However, I do not see why it is true. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

**Update:** Using the convolution argument as suggested in the answer, by induction, I have:

\begin{align*}
f_{S_{n,X}}(s; \lambda) &= \int\cdots\int_{\{(x_1, \dots, x_n): x_1+\cdots+x_n =s\}} f(x_1, \dots, x_n) dx_1\cdots dx_n \\
&= \int\cdots\int_{\{(x_1, \dots, x_n): x_1+\cdots+x_n =s\}} f_X(x_1)\dots, f_X(x_n) dx_1\cdots dx_n \\
&= \dots
\end{align*}

I do not know how to reduce from this to the integration given in the answer. Or how to understand the integrand given in the answer.

Comment: The probabilistic way would be to note that, for every real number $t$, $$E(e^{itX})=E(e^{itY}e^{\lambda Y})/m_Y(\lambda),$$ and to deduce by independence that, for every $n$, $$E(e^{itS_n^X})=E(e^{itS_n^Y}e^{\lambda S_n^Y})/m_Y(\lambda)^n,$$ which is equivalent to $$f_{S_n^X}(s)=f_{S_n^Y}(s)e^{\lambda s}/m_Y(\lambda)^n,$$ that is, the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability density function for $S_{n,X}$ is the [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the probability density functions of $X$ (assuming the $(X_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ are i.i.d.):
$$
f_{S_n,X}(s)=\int\cdots\int f_X(s-x_1;\lambda)\cdots f_X(x_{n-2}-x_{n-1};\lambda)\,f_X(x_{n-1};\lambda)\,\mathrm dx_1\cdots\mathrm dx_{n-1},
$$
so
\begin{align*}
f_{S_n,X}&(s)\\
&=\int\cdots\int {\mathrm e}^{\lambda\left((s-x_1)+(x_1-x_2)+\dots+(x_{n-2}-x_{n-1})+x_{n-1}\right)-n\kappa_Y(\lambda)}\,f_Y(s-x_1)\cdots f_Y(x_{n-1})\,\mathrm dx_1\cdots\mathrm dx_{n-1}\\
&={\mathrm e}^{\lambda s-n\kappa_Y(\lambda)}\,(\underbrace{f_Y*\cdots*f_Y}_{n\text{ times}})(s)\\
&={\mathrm e}^{\lambda s-n\kappa_Y(\lambda)}\,f_{S_n,Y}(s).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I still do not quite get how to write the integrand in your first formula. I know it is necessary to have $x_1+\cdots+x_n =s$ in total. Hence, we only have $(n-1)$-time integration. Could you explain a bit more on how to get the integrand, please?

Comment: Please see my update. How do I reduce from that to your formula, please? More importantly, how to interpret it?

Comment: By definition of the convolution, the pdf of $X_1+X_2$ is $f_{S_2,X}(s)=\int f_X(s-x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$. You can prove the general formula by induction on $n$. As an illustration, the pdf of $X_1+X_2+X_3$ is $f_{S_3,X}(s)=\int f_X(s-y)f_{S_2,X}(y)\,\mathrm dy=\iint f_X(s-y)f_X(y-x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$.